# Chrome Extension : Close certain number of inactive tabs from the right

Tags: google-chrome-extensions, browser-tabs

Now I know that there are extensions like [CloseAllInactiveTabs](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/close-all-inactive-window/oijajpbdfkajbjhobaaoaddnfnpcigig) to close all inactive tabs.
But I need to keep several tabs (from the left) open and close all other tabs from the right.
I sometimes need this feature when I have several important tabs open on the left
and I want to close all the other unnecessary tabs from the right.

So , my question is : are there any extensions that let me set the number of tabs to keep open while closing all other inactive tabs from the right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a very quick and easy solution. Right clicking on the rightmost required tab gives you this option: **Close tabs to the right**

Clicking on it does exactly what I needed  :)

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the [Tab Wrangler](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tab-wrangler/egnjhciaieeiiohknchakcodbpgjnchh)? You can set tabs to close after a certain amount of time and you can also specify the minimum number of tabs you want to stay open at all times.

The tabs that are auto-closed are saved by the extension, so you can always re-open them later.

Comment: Does it give the options to perform close manually with Tab Wrangler?

Comment: Not as far as I can see. It does however do most of what you stated in your question.